# Why I am not able to get two list views which are deviding equally the alert dialog window?

Tags: android

how to get the two list views which should equally divide the alert dialog even though adapter is not set, the lists should occupy equal space in dialog,
I am trying to set this view to my alert dialog but  upper list is wrapping completely, where as lower list is occupying almost all space of dialog window... any solution for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/header_strip">

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >    


  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/cartList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg"/>



</LinearLayout> 



<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >   



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/shopList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **wrap_content** instead of **fill_parent** in your **ListView** and **LinearLayout**.

Answer (score 0):

You are having LinearLayout extra that are wrapping the ListView, you can just have the both the ListViews with `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Simply this can do,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cartList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:scrollingCache="false" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/shopList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollingCache="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```